# get certificate of sender by a transaction id in hyperledger fabric

Tags: transactions, certificate, hyperledger-fabric, chaincode

I am using the `GoLang` SDK to interact with a Fabric network in chaincode, but I cannot find a way to get the certificate from a transaction ID to find out who signed the transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For client SDK, you can use `QueryTransaction` as [found here](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/pkg/client/ledger#Client.QueryTransaction) which returns a `ProcessedTransaction` object based on the tx id. This will have information of the signer of the transaction. The object will [look like this](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/third_party/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer#ProcessedTransaction). You then use the object in [this function](https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/third_party/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/common#Envelope) to get a transaction envelope and finally use `GetSignature` function. This wil return bytes so you got to convert to string.

Comment: thanks you, but I just have ID of a transaction, so how to get certificate of sender

Comment: @TiếnThànhNguyễn Just updated the answer. This will work.

Comment: yep, Thank you for all your help!